# Making a function for matching on multiple dependent variables, purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I want to estimate the matched treatment effect using the `Matching` package on multiple dependent variables.

For just a single dependent variable, I can run the below which returns what I want:

```
library(carData)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(Matching)

matching_df <- Mroz %>% 
  mutate(wc = case_when(wc == "yes" ~ "TRUE", 
                        wc == "no" ~ "FALSE")) %>% 
  drop_na(k5, k618, age, wc, hc, lfp)

matching_df$wc <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)

ps1 <- glm(wc ~ k5 + k618 + age + hc, 
           family = binomial, data = matching_df)

pscore <- ps1$fitted.values
matching_df <- cbind(matching_df, pscore)

Y <- matching_df$lfp
Tr <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)
  
psm1 <- Matching::Match(
  Y = Y, 
  Tr = Tr, 
  X = pscore, 
  estimand = "ATT", 
  M = 1, 
  replace = TRUE, 
  caliper = 0.05, 
  version = "fast")

summary(psm1)

Estimate...  0.17479 
SE.........  0.044963 
T-stat.....  3.8873 
p.val......  0.00010135 

Original number of observations..............  753 
Original number of treated obs...............  212 
Matched number of observations...............  207 
Matched number of observations  (unweighted).  1074 

Caliper (SDs)........................................   0.05 
Number of obs dropped by 'exact' or 'caliper'  5
```

But when I try and make a function using `purrr:map_dfr` so I can repeat this operation for multiple dependent variables, it returns an error. This is my attempt at the function:

```
vars <- c("lfp", "lwg", "inc")
names(vars) <- vars

matching_fcn <- function(.x){

  matching_df <- Mroz %>% 
    mutate(wc = case_when(wc == "yes" ~ "TRUE", 
                          wc == "no" ~ "FALSE")) %>% 
    drop_na(k5, k618, age, wc, hc, .x)

  matching_df$wc <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)

  ps1 <- glm(wc ~ k5 + k618 + age + hc, 
             family = binomial, data = matching_df)

  pscore <- ps1$fitted.values
  matching_df <- cbind(matching_df, pscore)

  Y <- matching_df$.x
  Tr <- as.logical(matching_df$wc)
    
  psm1 <- Matching::Match(
    Y = Y, 
    Tr = Tr, 
    X = pscore, 
    estimand = "ATT", 
    M = 1, 
    replace = TRUE, 
    caliper = 0.05, 
    version = "fast")

  summary(psm1)

}

purrr::map_dfr(
  .x = all_of(vars),
  .f = matching_fcn)
```

```
Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `lfp` is a `summary.Match` object.
x Column `lwg` is a `summary.Match` object.
x Column `inc` is a `summary.Match` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Ultimately, I would like a tibble which includes the name of the dependent variable in one column, then the estimate, se, T-stat, and p.val that are returned by the Matching::Match function in other columns

Comment: I noticed you just provided `Mroz`, next time please do this in the first place, thanks.

Comment: My bad, and genuine apologies for making you spend more time on this

Comment: No prob, made fun to analyze your approach:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `summary(psm1)` can't be put into a tibble. So choose some values of `psm1` and make your own. Further, `drop_na` is no good idea and will bias your results.

```
library(Matching)
vars <- c("dependent_var_1", "dependent_var_2", "dependent_var_3")
names(vars) <- vars

matching_fcn <- function(.x){
  # matching_df <- matching_df %>% 
  #   drop_na(covar_1, covar_2, covar_3, covar_4, covar_5, covar_6, covar_7, treat_1, .x)
  
  ps1 <- glm(treat_1 ~ covar_1 + covar_2 + covar_3 + covar_4 + covar_5 + covar_6 + covar_7, 
             family = binomial, data = matching_df)
  
  pscore <- ps1$fitted.values
  matching_df <- cbind(matching_df, pscore)
  
  Y <- matching_df[[.x]]
  Tr <- matching_df$treat_1
  
  psm1 <- Matching::Match(
    Y = Y, 
    Tr = Tr, 
    X = pscore, 
    estimand = "ATT", 
    M = 1, 
    replace = TRUE, 
    caliper = 0.05, 
    version = "fast")
  p <- 1 - pnorm(abs(psm1$est.noadj/psm1$se.standard))
  with(psm1, tibble(dv=.x, est=est.noadj, se=se.standard, p=p, ndrops=ndrops))
}
```

### Usage and result

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
purrr::map_df(
  .x =  tidyselect::all_of(vars),
  .f = matching_fcn)
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   dv                 est    se       p ndrops
#   <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 dependent_var_1  0.652 0.231 0.00238      8
# 2 dependent_var_2 -0.216 0.188 0.125        8
# 3 dependent_var_3 -0.506 0.249 0.0210       8
```

---

*Data*

```
v <- c('covar_1', 'covar_2', 'covar_3', 'covar_4', 'covar_5', 'covar_6', 
       'covar_7', 'treat_1', 'dependent_var_1', 'dependent_var_2', 'dependent_var_3')
set.seed(830595665)
matching_df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*length(v)), 100, length(v), dimnames=list(c(), v)))
matching_df$treat_1 <- +(matching_df$treat_1 > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @jay.sf! This helps a lot. If I don't include `drop_na()`, the code breaks at the line `matching_df <- cbind(matching_df, pscore)` with the error: "`Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 25128, 24922`"

Comment: @C.Robin Of course it does, because you have missings in your data. What I meant is you should impute them and not just delete the obs.

Comment: Ok that's given me something to look into. Thanks again